# Add new column in Pandas DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe in Pandas for example:

```
Col1 Col2
A     1 
B     2
C     3
```

Now if I would like to add one more column named Col3 and the value is based on Col2. In formula, if Col2 > 1, then Col3 is 0, otherwise would be 1. So, in the example above. The output would be:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
A    1    1
B    2    0
C    3    0
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate to the mentioned. Look into the contents, not just the subjects.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You just do an opposite comparison. `if Col2 <= 1`. This will return a boolean Series with `False` values for those greater than 1 and `True` values for the other. If you convert it to an `int64` dtype, `True` becomes `1` and `False` become `0`,

```
df['Col3'] = (df['Col2'] <= 1).astype(int)
```

If you want a more general solution, where you can assign any number to `Col3` depending on the value of `Col2` you should do something like:

```
df['Col3'] = df['Col2'].map(lambda x: 42 if x > 1 else 55)
```

Or:

```
df['Col3'] = 0
condition = df['Col2'] > 1
df.loc[condition, 'Col3'] = 42
df.loc[~condition, 'Col3'] = 55
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much for your advice. I have tried this and it's working!

Comment: Can I use df['col4'] = df['col2', 'col1'].map(lambda x: 20 if x > 1 elif x > 10 x:40 else 100)

Comment: @Payne, no, this wouldn't work, only for exact one column

Comment: I have a  problem with date not serializable in JSON output. I have several date range

Comment: Hi @VMAtm, how can I use multiple conditions to add a new column?      For example, if I have first both columns with numeric values and I want to use conditions as `if col1 > 2 and col2 > 1`. So, for this scenario how can I utilize above `lambda` solution?  Help me, please!

Comment: @AbdulRehman If you have a new question, ask it, do not use comments for discussion

Comment: Hi @VMAtm, sure, i have posted a question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/49586471/7644562                                              Can you take a look, please!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I found for adding a column to a DataFrame was to use the "add" function.  Here's a snippet of code, also with the output to a CSV file. Note that including the "columns" argument allows you to set the name of the column (which happens to be the same as the name of the np.array that I used as the source of the data).

```
#  now to create a PANDAS data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data = FF_maxRSSBasal, columns=['FF_maxRSSBasal'])
# from here on, we use the trick of creating a new dataframe and then "add"ing it
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = FF_maxRSSPrism, columns=['FF_maxRSSPrism'])
df = df.add( df2, fill_value=0 )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = FF_maxRSSPyramidal, columns=['FF_maxRSSPyramidal'])
df = df.add( df2, fill_value=0 )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = deltaFF_strainE22, columns=['deltaFF_strainE22'])
df = df.add( df2, fill_value=0 )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = scaled, columns=['scaled'])
df = df.add( df2, fill_value=0 )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = deltaFF_orientation, columns=['deltaFF_orientation'])
df = df.add( df2, fill_value=0 )
#print(df)
df.to_csv('FF_data_frame.csv')
```

Comment: does not work bro