# How to add k-means predicted clusters in a column to a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a question about kmeans clustering in python.

So I did the analysis that way:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

km = KMeans(n_clusters=12, random_state=1)
new = data._get_numeric_data().dropna(axis=1)
km.fit(new)
predict=km.predict(new)
```

How can I add the column with cluster results to my first dataframe "data" as an additional column? Thanks!

Comment: so you are essentially asking how to add a column to a dataframe? Such as in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942506/add-new-column-in-pandas-dataframe-python

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming the column length is as the same as each column in you dataframe `df`, all you need to do is this:

```
df['NEW_COLUMN'] = pd.Series(predict, index=df.index)
```