# how to get the final predicted column after I plot the kmeans clusters

Tags: r, algorithm, machine-learning, k-means

I am trying to learn machine learning and I am stuck at some point in kmeans algorithm. I have two questions on kmeans.

1. I have gone through many kmeans algorithm example and most of them stops as soon as the kmeans cluster plot is done in graph. but I want the final predicted column to find the complete answer. Can I know how can I get the corresponding data.

For example, if I have three clusters and I want to get the records for different clusters and want to assign some value for them in my predicted column. what should I do?

2. when I am doing the plotting for cluster, I am using only two of the observations from my entire dataset. What happens when I have more observations in my dataset and there is a dependency on the columns and I want to make use of them as well. Do I need to create separate cluster plots for these and then start analysing them as well?

Comment: Can you show us what code you've run (including some sample data), what it outputs, and what you're expecting?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was trying to solve the titanic survival problem following a different algorithm and since I studies kmeans I was trying to apply the same on titanic problem. The code is quite big to fit in this comment.. I have written the code and have generated the kmeans cluster point . However, I am stuck after that. I am not getting a way to map the clusters to the input dataset..

Comment: okay.. while searching for the answer I had got the below thing in stackoverflow. But its in Python. I want to do the exact thing using R. 
[link]  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372188/how-to-add-k-means-predicted-clusters-in-a-column-to-a-dataframe-in-python)

Comment: Then definitely go ahead and add in the code you've used so far, just like you see in that other python question.