# Add new column to Python Pandas DataFrame based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset with various columns as below:

`discount   tax   total   subtotal  productid
 3.98      1.06   21.06      20      3232 
 3.98      1.06   21.06      20      3232 
 3.98       6     106        100     3498 
 3.98       6     106        100     3743 
 3.98       6     106        100     3350 
 3.98       6     106        100     3370 
 46.49     3.36   66.84      63       695`

Now, I need to add a new column **Class** and assign it the value of `0` or `1` on the base of the following conditions:

```
if:
    discount > 20%
    no tax
    total > 100
then the Class will 1
otherwise it should be 0
```

I have done it with a single condition but I don't how can I accomplish it under multiple conditions.

Here's wIat i have tried:

```
df_full['Class'] = df_full['amount'].map(lambda x: 1 if x > 100 else 0)
```

> I have taken a look at all other similar questions but couldn't find any solution for my problem.I have tried all of the above-mentioned posts but stuck on this error:
>
> **`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`**

Here's in the case of first posted answer, i have tried it as:

```
df_full['class'] = np.where( ( (df_full['discount'] > 20) & (df_full['tax'] == 0 ) & (df_full['total'] > 100) & df_full['productdiscount'] ) , 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 49):

You can apply an arbitrary function across a dataframe row using [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

In your case, you could define a function like:

```
def conditions(s):
    if (s['discount'] > 20) or (s['tax'] == 0) or (s['total'] > 100):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

And use it to add a new column to your data:

```
df_full['Class'] = df_full.apply(conditions, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 8):

Judging by the image of your data is rather unclear what you mean by a `discount` 20%.

However, you can likely do something like this.

```
df['class'] = 0 # add a class column with 0 as default value

# find all rows that fulfills your conditions and set class to 1
df.loc[(df['discount'] / df['total'] > .2) & # if discount is more than .2 of total 
       (df['tax'] == 0) & # if tax is 0
       (df['total'] > 100), # if total is > 100 
       'class'] = 1 # then set class to 1
```

Note that `&` means `and` here, if you want `or` instead use `|`.