# How to fill in multiple boolean criteria in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

`I found an alternate answer here` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586471/add-new-column-to-python-pandas-dataframe-based-on-multiple-conditions)

My dataframe currently looks like this

```
          date  new_cases   new_deaths  new_tests   year    month   day weekday
0   2019-12-31  0.0                 0.0       NaN   2019    12      31   1
1   2020-01-01  0.0                 0.0       NaN   2020    1        1   2
2   2020-01-02  0.0                 0.0       NaN   2020    1        2   3
```

I want to pass an code which will average out the 'new_cases' for weekday and weekend
my code currently look like this but I can only pass 1 condition which is ' == 6 '. I want to pass multiple criteria, for example, == (4,5,6)

```
covid_df[covid_df.weekday == 6].new_cases.mean()
```

Any clue?

Comment: Create a new column that codes whether a particular row is a weekday or not (e.g. is_weekday); then do a groupby over that column and then average.

Comment: That sounds good. Will try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `isin`:

```
# you can use `loc` to access `new_cases` also
days = [4, 5, 6]
df.loc[df.weekday.isin(days), "new_cases"].mean()
```

which selects the rows whose `weekday` is in the `days` list; and then selects `new_cases` column.

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby()` date being a weekday or weekend.  Following code sources and demonstrates this.

```
import requests
import io
import pandas as pd

dfall = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(requests.get(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv").text))
dfall["date"] = pd.to_datetime(dfall["date"])

dtlcols = ["date", "iso_code", "location", "continent"]
cols = ["new_cases", "new_deaths", "new_tests"]
dfall.loc[dfall["iso_code"].eq("GBR"), dtlcols + cols].groupby(
    dfall["date"].dt.dayofweek.isin([5, 6]), as_index=False
).agg({**{c: "last" for c in dtlcols}, **{c: "mean" for c in cols}})
```

|  | date | iso_code | location | continent | new_cases | new_deaths | new_tests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-07-02 00:00:00 | GBR | United Kingdom | Europe | 9536.18 | 288.555 | 456697 |
| 1 | 2021-07-04 00:00:00 | GBR | United Kingdom | Europe | 9214.97 | 204.614 | 393841 |

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am too beginner to understand that. Thanks anyway for your answer! This code could solve my question as well, but I'm not sure how it works, hope somebody will answer that for me.

Comment: I'm a lazy typist :-). the only syntax sugar is building which columns we want in aggregate result with `agg()`